# How do I get the Publish information to show up in the output window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get the publishing information to show up in my output window when I use the publish wizard from the context menu.

Right now when I go through the publish it only generates two lines:

> ------ Publish started: Project: NerdDinner, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>
> Project "NerdDinner.csproj" (MSDeployPublish target(s)):
>
> Done building project "NerdDinner.csproj".

Does anyone have any idea why it's not showing the details of the publish?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your in your Options->Project and Solutions->Build and Run->MsBuild Project build output vebosity is at least set to Normal.

This should so you all the files that are being copied etc when you Publish.

Comment: Yeah right now I have them on Detailed, and the Build portion in the output window is outputting correctly, it's just the publish part that's blank.